# iOS Objects out of bounds

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uiview

I'm having some issues with a UIView and UITableView that I have created. When I scale the UIView and UITableView on the story board interface builder it looks fine and fits the screen. When I run it on my iPhone 6plus it also looks fine and is perfect. However, when I run it on the iOS simulator or an iPhone 4 plugged in it seems to be out of the screens bounds. I am new at developing so I'm not sure how to set constraints on them so they fit the width of the screen or proportionally scale. Here is an image of what it looks like:

[image]

Again I'm just not sure how to make them fit to the screens width and would greatly appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: Did you add constraints to your views?

Comment: I think you should also post screenshot about what it should be.

Answer (score 0):

So two ways to fit for different screens:

1. use autolayout, make the height and width contraints equal to the screen width and height.
2. manually setup your UIView's frame or bounds, use `[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]` to get the device screen size your app is running, and assign the size to your views.

Either way is ok. but I suggest you use auto layout from storyboard first

Answer (score 0):

You need to add constraints to your views explicitly; if you don't, the system adds them for you, and they're usually not the ones you want (it adds top, left, width, and height constraints). Your views should have constraints to the leading and trailing edges of the superview (the controller's self.view) to make them be the width of the screen on any device. You also need vertical constraints to properly place the UIView and UITableView where you show in your image.

Answer (score 0):

Your suspicions about how to solve this issue are correct. Auto Layout (aka constraints) is the technique that allows iOS apps to adjust your interface to fit screens of any size.

Auto Layout can be a big topic, so I won't try to teach it in this answer. Instead, here's the Apple documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Here's a blog post that I wrote that might help you understand the underlying concepts:

https://bradbambara.wordpress.com/2014/03/15/auto-layout-concepts-in-ios/

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to make this work..

1st: by using [Autolayout contraints](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1)

2nd: Manually/programmatically `((DEVICE_WIDTH) - ((MARGIN) * 2))` sample for manual computation...

also if you needed this, to determine the device your are app is running `[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size` to get the screen size.. ;)

```
BOOL isIPhone = ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom]   == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone);

BOOL isIPhone5 = ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568);

//BOOL isIPhone6 = ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 667.0);

//BOOL isIPhone6P = ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 736.0);

BOOL isIPad = ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom]   == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad);
```